# Cannot find string value in array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am unable to check if something is string or not.

I have this array:

```
ji1 = [:Districts,:Winter_Rain, :Hot_Weather_Rain, :South_West_Monsoon, :North_West_Monsoon, :Total]
```

I am trying to map this array using this code:

```
hash_data = ji1.map do |el|
  {title:el, field:el, sorter:"string", editor:true}
end
```

This works, but when I use this array:

```
ji1 = ["Districts",:Winter_Rain, :Hot_Weather_Rain, :South_West_Monsoon, :North_West_Monsoon, :Total]
```

with this code,

```
hash_data = ji1.map do |el|
  hash_data = ji.map do |el|
    if el == "Districts"
      abort(el)
    else
      puts el
    end
    {title:el, field:el, sorter:"string", editor:true}
  end
```

When I am using code above I don't see any action I am expecting to abort the code when el == "Districts". I need to compare my first array.

Comment: `hash_data = ji.map do |el|` should be `hash_data = ji1.map do |el|`, typo?

Comment: _"I don't see anything happening when I am using this array:"_ - It is not clear what you want to happen.

Comment: Fixed that that is not the problem

Comment: When I am using first array I can't compare as string because it is symbol

Comment: `el.to_s == "Districts"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you have an array of symbols you are comparing it with string. Converting the element to string `(el.to_s == "Districts")` will work.

```
ji1 = [
  :Districts, :Winter_Rain, :Hot_Weather_Rain, :South_West_Monsoon,
  :North_West_Monsoon, :Total
]

hash_data = ji1.map do |el|
  if el.to_s == "Districts"
    abort(el)
  else
    puts el
  end
  { title:el, field:el, sorter:"string", editor:true }
end
```

Note: The above code only converts `el` to string for comparison purpose. If you want it `String` in the return value you might want to change `el` in the loop itself

Like this:

```
hash_data = ji1.map do |el|
  el = el.to_s
  ...
  ...
end
```